# Trouble converting .ui to .py

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to create a GUI for a small program I've made. I have Qt5.2.1 installed and PyQt4(which is located in my Python34 folder). I have been watching youtube videos and googling for several hours. (Mostly following https://youtu.be/Dmo8eZG5I2w?t=8m23s)

What I have been doing is opening the command prompt at the directory my .ui is saved in (Qt\Qt5.2.1\msvc2012_64\bin>). Here I have tried `pyuic4 -x convert.ui -o convert.py`

This brings up the error that `"C:\Python34\python" is not a recognized internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. While this is the location of the PyQt4, there is no subdirectory called python inside of Python34?

If I try instead `C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/pyuic4.bat -x convert.ui -o convert.py` I get the same error as above.

One thing that has had mild success was one suggestion I found on here to do `pyuic4 -w convert.ui > convert.py`. This created a new file, but when I opened it in IDLE the document was empty. I'll admit I have no idea what -w does.

What am I missing? I also have Python27 and Python30 installed, but they are their own folders on C:. Only 34 contains PyQt4.

Comment: What do you mean "PyQt4 is located in my Python34 file".   Take care whether you are talking about "files" or "directories".   I think you are referring to the directory C:\Python34, and you mean that there is a directory called PyQt4 located inside that.   Don't call directories "files".   Directories can be referred to as "folders", and you might find that easier to understand.

Comment: If you have correctly installed Python3.4, there should be a file called python.exe in the folder `C:\Python34\`.  Is there?

Comment: Sorry, I was mixing up some terms. I went back and edited, hopefully should be correct now. I went and checked the Python34, I didn't see a .exe. I guess that means it didn't get installed properly. I never though about that as I've been using 2.7 afaik. I'm going to go play with that and see what happens. Thanls

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error but I resolved it by pasting the python.exe
in "C:\Python34\python.exe", and python.exe should be of version 3.4 in your case.

Answer (score -1):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> I had to reinstall both Python34 and PyQt4. Seems they were not correctly installed the first time.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it non-repro?

Comment: @miken32 Yes, but that doesn't change the fact that solutions belong in answers, not questions.

Comment: Right, just wondering why no VTC

Comment: @miken32 I'm out of close votes (and was out when I posted the answer, too). Don't worry, I've bookmarked the question for tomorrow.